# C# Label not showing at loading screen

Tags: c#, screen, loading

In an application that I'm writing I have to load a lot of data in a listview after I push a certain button. Because this might take a while, I want to show a simple loading-screen to the user.
I did this by creating a very simple form with 1 label on it. I do a Form.Show() before I start fetching the data, and a Form.Close() once it's finished. This works partially: I get the loading screen, it closes at the right time, but as you can see the label isn't displayed.

I know I should program this loagind screen-problem with the help of a BackgroundWorker, but I'm not a very experienced C# programmer so if I could just somehow force the label to display I would be more than happy.

Is it possible to force this label to display immediately, or do I have to find another solution?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Might be a daft questions but -- have you set label1.Visible = true? Is it located in a part of the window that can be seen? Is the text colour the same as the background colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI Message pump has no time to update the label / refresh the screen since the loading process takes up all resources.

You can try to force the update of the label, by calling `Application.DoEvents()`.  Although, using 'Application.DoEvents' is imho a 'code-smell', and thus indicates that the design is not that good.  So, it should be avoided.

Therefore, using DoEvents is surely not the best solution to this problem.  It is merely a symptom-fix.

You've mentionned the best solution already yourself: use another thread to load all the data.  (You can indeed use a `BackGroundWorker` for this purpose, since this will abstract away a lot of plumbing code).

Comment: Application.DoEvents() is to be avoided.

Comment: I totally agree.  That's why I say that it isn't the best solution and a backgroundworker should be preferred.

Comment: And still I'm just going to use the simple solution, which is the Application.DoEvents() method, which does just the thing I asked. 
It's a really simple program with not a lot of lines. It may not be very professional to use the mentioned method, but it's also not a very professional application ;). 
Thanks for your solution Frederik, altough I have the feeling you're going to feel bad for giving it :).

Answer (score 3):

BackgroudWorker is very easy to use , even c# is very powerful and simple langugage

[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

i am almost sure that , you would not need any more help with BackGroundWorker but if you have any query , you canm always post on SO ?? Collabartive Intelligence is what SO is?